# LED Case Lighting Installation

Tags: power-supply, case-mods, molex

I just purchased the [following LED Kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IHARBFW) to use in my Corsair 760T case. What should I purchase in addition with what's included to have these LEDs work inside my case using a 1300W G2 PSU?

The bundle I purchased comes with a wire tail on the barrel plug (red & black) as shown in the attached JPEG.

After connecting the barrel plug to the small white controller box, do I then connect the wire tail to female end of the molex (matching red & black lanes) of this [weird cable that I wanted to buy](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=102&cp_id=10245&cs_id=1024501&p_id=1317&seq=1&format=2&ref=cj) ? And then I connect the second female end of the molex to the computer PSU?

How do I use my 1300W PSU to power the LEDs?

Would this process also require the use of a crimp tool?

Answer (score 2):

Red is +5V, yellow is +12V, black are both grounds (the one on the red side is for the 5V, the one on the yellow side is for the 12V but I'm pretty sure you can use both of them).

Here's the exact pinout, just for reference :

[image: Pinout image]

So if your LED strip uses 12V, then cut its power cable, insert the ground wire into one of the ground pins (the two at the center) of the male molex connector (coming from your PSU), and insert the positive wire into the +12V pin of the molex connector. You can use whatever you want for insulation, assuming both wires are held together they should stay in place and provide enough electrical contact to power the LEDs.

The second product you mentioned - the weird two female connectors molex cable is useless to you as you can't even connect it to your PSU. You maybe wanted to buy [this cable](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?c_id=102&cp_id=10245&cs_id=1024501&p_id=1316&seq=1&format=2) instead which has a connector that can connect to your PSU. In this case, cut the black and yellow wires and solder them to your LED controller's power cable, like this :

[image: Connector photo]

And no crimp too needed, it depends on your level of perfectionism. You can use my dirty solution that I proposed above which just requires you to insert the wires into a connector and secure all of that with some duct tape, you can do better by using an actual molex connector and soldering the wires to it as proposed in my second solution, or if you really want to you can buy a molex connector and crimp it to the power wires of your LED strip, but that's way too overkill for such a simple mod.

Comment: Thanks André for the prompt response. As you stated, I incorrectly referenced the wrong 4-pin molex connector. 

Using the male to female 4-pin molex connector without crimp or solder tools, can the connection be made by removing the female pin plate and twisting the wires together sealing them with electrical tape?

Also, being that only two of the four wires will be used (Yellow & Black), is it suggested to completely remove the other ground (Black) and 5v positive (Red) cables from the connection?

Comment: @user339807 Please keep in mind that the PSU easily delivers dozens of ampères... (1300W -- what the heck!) so make sure that your insulation is sufficient and a short circuit never ever occurs. Fire hazard!

Comment: @mpy true, but a good PSU also has short-circuit protection that'll instantly switch the power off if a short is detected.

Comment: @André OK, I never tested this on my new PSU, but I think the old ones delivered or died... `;)`

Comment: @mpy I tried to kill a low-end Delta PSU from about 2006 by shorting it, no luck, switches itself off with no damage. It still works in one of my older computers. But of course things will be different if we're talking about [this kind of PSU](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWt3St_MhSY). ;)

Answer (score 0):

I did this  same mod, routing RGB LED tape through the case.

[image]
See the box lower right external to the case.

[image]

I had the choice of using the PSU power, or powering it with an external adapter.
I chose to run it via a External wall wart adapter, first a 500ma one , which was not enough total power when everything was on full, then a 800ma one which was sufficent power. This was a single reel.

[image]

You can see the box there on the back (left bottom), with the external adapter wire that is headed to it.

I am very happy that I chose using external power, because it shorted to the case 2 times, and had to be adjusted (works great now).  And I can use it as general lighting when putting boards and disks and all in and out, because it is independant.

At the least make sure you have some sort of fuse or curcuit breaker in there. shorting to the case will be much easier and a way bigger disaster using the same +12 used in the rest of the machine, this stuff is not rope light with the full insulations.
It did not surprise me when it shorted out, although I am sure someone using much more care and with a different case could prevent that. Then the tape comes loose and pow.
Led tape - $8
Adapter for powering it - $16
Loosing your computer over a mod - Priceless

Comment: That is actually a brilliant alternative idea Psycogeek! I like your innovating way of thinking. My original efforts will be to follow André’s advice in routing the cables through a molex to the PSU. However, being that my computer case is white which matches the IR Controler Box, I will also consider your method. I greatly appreciate the photos you provided as you have a beautiful looking machine! Now I will build up my reputation so that I can reward the two of you with these very helpful solutions. I very much appreciate everyone's help and time!